# Is a response-body allowed for a HTTP-DELETE-request?

Tags: rest, http, http-delete

I assume the response code 200 always allows for a response-body, but I can't find any explicit mention of response-bodies for DELETE-requests.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

It is explicitly mentioned here in the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7/)

The short answer is:

You **should include** a response body with an entity describing the deleted item/resource if you return **200**.

**202** is something like an asynchronous request/response return status.

**204** says explicitly that you do not include a response body

Comment: Upvote for referencing the HTTP spec.  Also be aware that they are updating the HTTP spec and clarifying many issues here http://tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/

Comment: +1 But the spec says you can return 200 ok if the response body  contains an entity "describing status" and not the entity deleted.

Comment: It actually says "includes an entity describing **the** status" - so returning the deleted entity with a "deleted" flag seems totally valid.

Comment: Must 202 (Accepted) response must be body included?

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you should usually respond with a 200 response code as per [the W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html):

> 9.7 DELETE
>
> The DELETE method requests that the
>   origin server delete the resource
>   identified by the Request-URI. This
>   method MAY be overridden by human
>   intervention (or other means) on the
>   origin server. The client cannot be
>   guaranteed that the operation has been
>   carried out, even if the status code
>   returned from the origin server
>   indicates that the action has been
>   completed successfully. However, the
>   server SHOULD NOT indicate success
>   unless, at the time the response is
>   given, it intends to delete the
>   resource or move it to an inaccessible
>   location.
>
> A successful response SHOULD be 200
>   (OK) if the response includes an
>   entity describing the status, 202
>   (Accepted) if the action has not yet
>   been enacted, or 204 (No Content) if
>   the action has been enacted but the
>   response does not include an entity.
>
> If the request passes through a cache
>   and the Request-URI identifies one or
>   more currently cached entities, those
>   entries SHOULD be treated as stale.
>   Responses to this method are not
>   cacheable.

Comment: You've mis-read the language. The codes are listed in ascending order and the order does not imply a preferred response. Each of a 200, 202, or a 204 response are equally acceptable as described in this text. The SHOULD only means that the codes are implemented with the usual conventions (e.g, 200 includes a body and 204 does not).