# Retrieve JSON in a DELETE request

Tags: json, rest, cherrypy

I'm trying to receive a JSON via DELETE to a cherrypy server using:

```
@cherrypy.tools.json_in()
def delete(self):
    data = cherrypy.request.json
```

But I always get an error (Looks like cherrypy just throw the json away...). Is there a way to retrieve the json?

I googled around and saw some people saying sending a DELETE with body is wrong, but [the specs](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) don't say anything.

Comment: there is nothing wrong in sending response body on DELETE request. Make sure you respond with response code 200. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581285/is-a-response-body-allowed-for-a-http-delete-request

Comment: @rubchick I'm trying to send a json to a cherrypy server, but when I try to access the json in the server, I get an error.

Comment: You at least need to tell CherryPy that DELETE might have a body via `request.methods_with_bodies`. See example at http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/config.html#cp-config-attaching-config-to-handlers

Comment: @fumanchu That works! If you make an answer I'll gladly accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Since the official documentation is not on cherrypy.org anymore, here is [the new one](https://docs.cherrypy.dev/en/latest/config.html#cp-config-attaching-config-to-handlers).

By default request is parameter as follow:

```
request.methods_with_bodies = ('POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH')
```

To allow a body for a DELETE http method you need to add DELETE to the above tuple.

If you use a class base dispatch:

```py
import cherrypy

class SetOPages:

    _cp_config = {"request.methods_with_bodies": ('POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE')}

    @cherrypy.expose
    def page(self):
        return "Hello, World!"
```

if you use a classic def dispatcher:

```py
import cherrypy

@cherrypy.expose
def page(self):
    return "Hello, world!"
page._cp_config = {"request.methods_with_bodies": ('POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I blame my bad reading skills...

From [the specs](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)...

> The DELETE method requests that the origin server **delete the resource identified by the Request-URI**

It still doesn't **explicit** say it shouldn't have a body, but...

Comment: While it is not restricted to have body in DELETE request, major web servers don't implement this, I think